# Can't get array elements previously declared to use it in render with ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, fetch

I've previously got an array from an API with fetch. I saved it into a variale "ids".The problem is that "ids" variable is empty in the render. How can I see the previously declared values that I save in the "ids" variable?

This is my actual code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactSVG from 'react-svg';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import avatar from './avatar.jpg'
import './component.css'

import Msg from './components/Msg';
import ItemMsg from './components/ItemMsg';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
var ids = [];
var componente = [];

class App extends Component {


  componentDidMount() {
     fetch('/todos/ids')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => ids = responseJson.data)
    .then(console.log)
  }

  render() {

    var id;

    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
      id = ids[i];
      componente.push(<li><ItemMsg idfromparent={id}/></li>);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar/>
        <Msg/>
        <ul>
          {componente}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why not to store it in component's state?

Comment: i tried, but i can't use the sate out of the return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactSVG from 'react-svg';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import avatar from './avatar.jpg'
import './component.css'

import Msg from './components/Msg';
import ItemMsg from './components/ItemMsg';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
     fetch('/todos/ids')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => this.setState({ids: responseJson.data}))
    .then(console.log)
  }

  render() {
    var ids = this.state && this.state.ids ? this.state.ids : []; 
    var componente = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.ids.length; i++) {
      componente.push(<li><ItemMsg key={ids[i]} idfromparent={ids[i].ID_Publicacion}/></li>);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar/>
        <Msg/>
        <ul>
          {componente}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't that the value of the list `ids` isn't updated, it is. The problem here is that your component has no reason to re-render based on the change in that variable even though it uses it in it's render. The only way to trigger a re-render of a component is by calling `setState`.

A way you can do this is using the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook. Do the async call, then call `setState`. The component is re-rendered and the populated value for `state.users` is used.

Here is a contrived example. I believe you can adapt it to your case:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      users: []
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('/users')
    .then(users => this.setState({ users });
}

render() {
  return (
    <ul> 
      { 
        this.state.users && this.state.users.map(user => <li> { user.name } </li>);
     }
    </ul>
    );
  }
}
```